# Instagram pending review take too long time

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

How many days for instagram review a sandbox app to go live, i submited all required documents including youtube URL (function interactive video), privacy policy and the my website url links to facebook fanpage (have no offical website).
It's been a week i submited and review still pending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently Instagram has stopped accepting submissions of new apps, That is the reason you are facing this problem to create new access token. 
https://techcrunch.com/2018/04/02/instagram-api-limit/
Although for the already registered app, you can still get more access token by adding the additional new users.

Comment: this article talking about setup instagram on facebook, so the client on https://www.instagram.com/developer/ being affected too ?

Comment: @ddawng.quang Yes. I have been waiting for 1 month and still pending review

Comment: the reviews are suspended due the Facebook privacy policies changes.

Comment: still waiting to August

Answer (score 0):

> Starting October 1st, only submissions for basic permissions on the
>   existing Instagram API will be reviewed. We will not be accepting
>   submissions for public_content, follower_list, comments, relationship,
>   or likes permission scopes. Developers are encouraged to build on the
>   new Instagram Graph API.